# Which classes are removed in Java 9? Get NoClassDefFoundError on Java 9. Java 8 work

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror, java-9

What classes were removed in Java 9?

On Java 8 my tool is working.

On Java 9 I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/image/codec/jpeg/JPEGCodec
```

It seems that some classes have been removed.

I use the Oracle JDK on Windows.

Comment: *"I use the Oracle JDK on Windows."* I suspect you made a typo. there and it should read *"I **misuse** the Oracle JDK on Windows."*. There would have been compilation  warnings on using those classes. **That** would have been the right time to figure out which non `com.sun` API to use.

Comment: @ Andrew Thompson: This error is generated somewhere in a compiled lib.
So how should I find or fix this error ;-)

Comment: Stop using that API. Simple.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[The JDK 9 release note](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/9all-relnotes-3704433.html#JSERN109) and [The one for removed features](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/9-removed-features-3745614.html).

They said

> client-libs/2d
>    Remove the com.sun.image.codec.jpeg package 
>   com.sun.image.codec.jpeg has been shipped as a non-standard API since JDK 1.2. It was always advertised as a stop-gap measure until a proper standard equivalent was provided. That replacement (javax.imageio) has been there since JDK 1.4. As a result JDK 9 finally removes the long deprecated com.sun.image.codec.jpeg API which has been flagged as intended for removal for several releases. Applications which still depend on it will need to be re-coded in order to run on JDK9.  See [JDK-8038838](http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8038838)